# ShareLaTeX - Nested 'Main'

Tags: sharelatex, nesting, revision-control, versions, subversion

I'm trying to create the version / revision copies within the ShareLatex structure itself. I would like to know if there is a way to nest 'main' inside each folder and compile that folder alone. If that's not possible, is there any other way to achieve this?

I'm yet to explore the SVN package as multiple people work on the same document simultaneously.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did a little bit of self research and finally stumbled upon this... which is working perfectly.

Press "Menu" -> choose the Main document to compile & it works flawlessly.

Only thing is... I need to manually update the path for each version folder.

Thanks anyone for attempting to help

[image]